# As a Google Apps Admin, how do I remove an ex-employee from a calendar event?

Tags: google-workspace, google-calendar

We have several ex-employees who are still listed as attendees for meetings.  Their google accounts have been deleted.  We have a catch-all account that is getting their reminders for events.  How do I remove them without getting the owner of the event involved?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I talked to the former Google Apps admin.  It turns out it is very simple.  Rather than go to the admin section, go straight to your own calendar.  From within your calendar, add the event's owner's calendar to your calendar view (from the bottom left).  Now select the specific event and edit it.  From the edit screen you can remove attendees.

Comment: That is simple to carry out but not simple to discover.